# react and socket io private messaging not working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

server side

```
 io.on('connection', function(socket){

  socket.on('user joined', function(data){
     socket.join(data.username);    
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('user disconnected');
  });

  socket.on('send private', function(data){
      console.log('sending private', data);
      io.in(data.to).emit('pmessage',data);
  })

});
```

client side

```
  handleSubmit(){
     var newMSG= {
        to: this.state.selectedFriend,
        from: this.props.user.username,
        message: 'new message yay'
       }
    this.state.socket.emit('send private', newMSG);
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    var self = this;

    self.state.socket.on('pmessage', function(data){
        console.log('receiving private!', data);
      document.getElementById('myprivates').innerHTML= "<p><em>"+data.message+"</em></p>";
    })  

  }
```

I can't get the 'pmessage' emit event to trigger, so I'm thinking I'm not doing the io.in() part right.  I'm trying to implement private communication using the users' usernames but I can't find clear examples or documentation on this.  I followed the docs on socket io so I should be close or working but it's not.

Comment: selectedFriend is a username*  and data.username is also a username, just for clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you have used the right react life cycle method but the way you are adding the data to the dom is not a good method in react. Try something like this.

```
        import React from 'react';
        import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

        const socket = io();

        class MyComponent extends React.Component {

          constructor() {
            super();
            this.state = { messages: []}

          }

         handleSubmit(){
             var newMSG= {
                to: this.state.selectedFriend,
                from: this.props.user.username,
                message: 'new message yay'
               }
            this.state.socket.emit('send private', newMSG);
          }

          componentDidMount(){
            var self = this;

            self.state.socket.on('pmessage', function(data){
                console.log('receiving private!', data);
                this.setState({messages:this.state.messages.concat(data)});
          }

         messagelist(){
           return this.state.messages.map((msg,i) => {
                 return <li key={i}> msg </li>
                });
         }


          render() {
            let messages = 

            return (
              <div>
                <h1>Messages</h1>
                <div>
                  {this.messagelist}
                </div>
              </div>
            );
          }
        }

    export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: thank you, I'm only doing this to test the response but I can't get that part to trigger.  I will implement this ultimately so thank you for the tip! :)

Answer (score 0):

The way we need to listen to new messages from socket has to be handled separately and make the component state to change with the new data.

I have added a simple example on how to do this. It may not work as it is and need some changes based on your business logic. But this should give you a fair idea on how to do it.

I didn't add a case where client talks to the server with a new message.But it's fairly simple to implement.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const socket = io();

class MyComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { messages: []}
    socket.on('pmessage', (newMessages) => this.handleStateChange(newMessages));
  }

  handleStateChange(newMessages) {
    this.setState({ messages: newMessages });
  }

  render() {
    let messages = this.state.messages.map((msg) => {
     return <li> msg </li>
    });

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Messages</h1>
        <div>
          {messages}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent/>, document.getElementById('private-messages'));
```